# asp.net jit multiple core slow

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, jit

Using IIS I'm Running Asp.net 4.5 and trying to find a way to improve jit times on a machine multiple(8) cores. The test I use is timing 100 different pages.
The machine i'm testing all this on is 4 core, 8 logical processors.

The maximum I see csc or w3p is 13% so it appears that it's only using 1 core.
I've read that since Asp.net 4.5 multicore jit is on by default. ok sure, it's still just 13%.
I read about ngen trying that over the all the dll's in the bin dir. This didn't really have any affect on the timing but by the perfView it seems to have done something.

Antivirus is off at the time of testing.

Test timings: peformed after the very first page has loaded

- Cold prejit (first run) 10.25 min
- Hot run (second run) 2.32 min
- Ngen then first run 10.24 min

**Perfview** JitStats

*Cold* prejit
-Process CPU Time: 161,038 msec
-Total Number of JIT compiled methods : 13,193
-Total MSec JIT compiling : 2,630
-JIT compilation time as a percentage of total process CPU time : 1.6%
This process does not use background JIT compilation

*Ngen* then first run
-Process CPU Time: 144,152 msec
-Total Number of JIT compiled methods : 4,604
-Total MSec JIT compiling : 608
-JIT compilation time as a percentage of total process CPU time : 0.4%
This process does not use background JIT compilation.

Comment: It might be worth asking this question over at: https://serverfault.com/

Comment: good point. thanks